# How is it I can remove an External Seagate Hard Drive from USB without unmounting?

Tags: linux, usb, external-hard-drive

I use Linux and when copying to USB, I have to explicitly unmount unless using `sync` which slows the copy. However recently I was given an external hard disk 2 TB Seagate and when I plugged this into Windows 10 I noticed that it had no `'Eject'` option. Hos is this possible?

Comment: (i don't remember the exact model number etc)

Comment: In windows 7, I do not see an eject button in explorer itself for external HDDs, but in the taskbar->hidden icons.

Comment: okay so one has to eject then via that - for sure?

Comment: I am not sure about that, but I used to eject using that. Couldn't find any other way.

Comment: I don't use Win 10, but is the option available in the context menu if you right-click on the drive in Explorer?

Comment: ah nope - i checked that!